# Pass value to Ember component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a Ember component that inits a video player. This player needs to be passed an ID to play the content.

The ID is being used as part of the Route `#/content/:uid/play`.

Whats the best way to fetch the UID and pass it to the component?

Comment: A property is generally passed too the component from the controller of the enclosing template. You have to mention the property being passed in the handlebar file also. Have a look at examples on this page. http://emberjs.com/guides/components/passing-properties-to-a-component/

Comment: Does the id exist anywhere beside the url (in one of your model's perchance)?  Is the component in the play template?  What's the model in the play template?